# Fitting width and height of html page contents to screen

Tags: css, html

I have created a table with rows in html and defined it's width and height parameters in css using pixel(px).
I'm using a 15.6" display pc to run it and everything goes well, but when i open the page in smaller screen pc, the table exceeds the screen margin.

Which unit should I use to define the width & height parameters so that, it will always fit the display of any media screen that opens the page?

Comment: I personaly use %: `width: 100%` That way if screen is smaller it automatically resizes to fit it. Was using px up until recently too until saw how bad my site looked on smaller screens. Turned px to % and it's way better now.

Comment: Thanks i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `Width: 1-100vw` and `height: 1-100vh;` on everything `(<p>,<div>,font-size etc.)`

You will also need to add in `min-height: 100vh;` and `min-width: 100vw;` to the `html,body` css. else it won't work.

This WILL ensure that it works properly. I used to use %, but in the end it didn't work out with scaling to the re-size ^^

See this for more info: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: Not a problem ^^

Please choose this as the answer so everyone can find it and know that's how to do it ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could set the width of the body to 100%. Another suggestion is to use

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height
>
> 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
>
> 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

can read about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Further read into [responsive web design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) might help you in the future.

Ex:

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700";
.rwd-table {
  margin: 1em 0;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.rwd-table th {
  display: none;
}
.rwd-table td {
  display: block;
}
.rwd-table td:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
.rwd-table td:before {
  content: attr(data-th) ": ";
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 6.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table td:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .25em .5em;
  }
  .rwd-table th:first-child, .rwd-table td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .rwd-table th:last-child, .rwd-table td:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 0 2em;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #444;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #34495E;
}

.rwd-table {
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .4em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rwd-table tr {
  border-color: #46637f;
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .rwd-table th, .rwd-table td {
    padding: 1em !important;
  }
}
.rwd-table th, .rwd-table td:before {
  color: #dd5;
}
```

```html
<h1>RWD List to Table</h1>
<table class="rwd-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Movie Title</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Gross</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">Star Wars</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">Adventure, Sci-fi</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1977</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$460,935,665</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">Howard The Duck</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">"Comedy"</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1986</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$16,295,774</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Movie Title">American Graffiti</td>
    <td data-th="Genre">Comedy, Drama</td>
    <td data-th="Year">1973</td>
    <td data-th="Gross">$115,000,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>&larr; Drag window (in editor or full page view) to see the effect. &rarr;</p>
```

Ref: [LINK](https://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg)